# Button Links in HTML

Tags: html, button

Hi guys I am a noob at Web development, I would like to know how to create a button that when clicked will take me to another page.

I have the link

```
<a target="_parent" href="TheTeam.html" class="button" id="team">Back to The Team</a>
```

Thank you

Comment: You could style a link to look like a button.  Or use a button element and attach a JavaScript event handler to it which redirects the user to another page.

Comment: That will take you to another page. It'll take you to `TheTeam.html` page, *if it exists in your file system*.